# Cannot get subpackage from its name with getApplicationInfo

Tags: java, android, package

I want to get that subpackage so its main activity is called when a tap is done in a notification.

The code that is failing is the following one:

```
apppack="com.example.add.myapplication.mysubpackage";
try
{
    ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(apppack, 0);
...
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With failing being that the PackageManager.NameNotFoundException is captured.

If that code is called with apppack="com.example.add.myapplication" instead of with the apppack shown in it no exception is thrown and I could use that package.

The class where the shown code is contained is in the package "com.example.add.myapplication".

I guess the error must be about some nomenclature in naming the subpackage, but I don't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [PackageManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) :

> parameter packageName String: The full name (i.e. com.google.apps.contacts) of an application.

The parameter *cannot* be a sub package.